# How to renewenvironment that wrap the base environment?

Tags: environments

I would like to add wrap something around an existing environment.

Consider an existing environment `sphinxVerbatim`, I would like to renew this environment by adding something before and after that environment call. I could write this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
\renewenvironment{sphinxVerbatim}[1]
    {\begin{code}\begin{sphinxVerbatim}{#1}}
    {\end{sphinxVerbatim}\end{code}}
```

In context, I would like to wrap my `code` environment around an existing environment named `sphinxVerbatim`:

```
\newtcolorbox{code}{breakable,enhanced,arc=0mm,colback=lightgray!5,colframe=lightgray}
```

Sphinx generates some code such as:

```
\begin{sphinxVerbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{c+cp}{\PYGZsh{}}\PYG{c+cp}{include} \PYG{c+cpf}{\PYGZlt{}stdio.h\PYGZgt{}}
\end{sphinxVerbatim}
```

and I would like to redeclare this environment for this `sphinxVerbatim` to be wrapped inside a `\begin{code}...\end{code}`.

The main issue I have with `sphinxVerbatim` is that the frame goes outside from the page area, I want it to be inside with some margin as shown below:

[image]

[image]
I thought I could simply redeclare `sphinxVerbatim`...

Comment: The `etoolbox` package defines `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` commands.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think I can do `\begin{something}` inside a `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` :(

Comment: You didn't give many details. Could you show what you're trying to obtain and what you tried?

Comment: @Bernard I've added some information to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may benefit from looking at the documentation for Sphinx: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html

The section on sphinxsetup mentions the ability to do things like adding a frame, coloring, etc. which should allow you to do the customizations that you like.

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't work. The standard Sphinx options are very ugly. I would like to declare a `code-block` inside a `tcolorbox` environment.